# loop through columns in an xts to find the max 3 values per column with the date in R

Tags: r, loops, max, xts, cbind

Here is my code, I loop through the column of my `DD xts` 
I store the 3 max values in `outl`

The problem is when I cbind the `outl` , I have the correct date for the first column but not for the others. Is there a way to correct that?

```
Outpout = NULL
i = 1
while (i<dim(DD)[2]+1){
  outl = sort(DD[,i], TRUE)[1:3]
i = i+1

Outpout = cbind(Outpout,outl)
}
```

Here is the result of my `Outpout`

```
                   outl     outl     outl     outl     outl     outl     outl     outl     outl
2015-08-12 17:00:00 382.0823 308.5812 382.7290 305.5518 306.5123 364.4946 359.3629 361.8381 358.2999
2014-06-30 17:00:00 363.0952 243.4499 307.9904 305.4652 177.9962 361.2023 348.1868 358.5445 350.9746
2016-06-30 17:00:00 327.6692 160.4543 193.0451 141.0073 128.6539 346.6693 328.9490 331.9964 327.2888
```

Maybe there is a better way to find the 3 max per column with the date asociated

my sample

```
                                                               a                              b
        2011-01-03 12:00:00                         2.838006e-01                        1.094922e+00
        2011-01-03 17:00:00                         6.655318e-01                        2.572599e+01
        2011-01-03 18:00:00                         1.364121e-01                        5.365103e-01
        2011-01-03 19:00:00                         1.805002e+01                        1.847452e-01
        2011-01-04 04:00:00                         2.765880e-01                        8.721402e-02
        2011-01-04 05:00:00                         3.213491e-02                        2.124598e-01
        2011-01-04 10:00:00                         1.482882e+00                        2.184471e+00
```

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: Do you have any ideas?